# PHP's register_shutdown_function to fire when a script is killed from the command line?

Tags: php, shutdown-hook

Is it possible to invoke a function when a cron process is killed from the command line (via Ctrl+c) or with the kill command?

I have tried `register_shutdown_function()`, but it doesn't seem to be invoked when the script is killed, but does get invoked when the script ends normally.

I am trying to log the result to a file and update a database value when a cron instance is killed automatically (ie. has been running too long).

Comment: What do you mean by "killed automatically": The system's time limit stopping the process, or PHP's stopping the script?

Comment: i have another cron instance that kills crons that have been running in the background after x seconds.

Comment: Maybe it'd simpler then to log in the cron script that kills ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to a [comment in the manual on `register_shutdown_function()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#26251), this can be done the following way:

> When using CLI ( and perhaps command
>   line without CLI - I didn't test it)
>   the shutdown function doesn't get
>   called if the process gets a SIGINT or
>   SIGTERM. only the natural exit of PHP
>   calls the shutdown function.  To
>   overcome the problem compile the
>   command line interpreter with
>   `--enable-pcntl` and add this code:
>
> ```
>  <?php
>  declare(ticks = 1); // enable signal handling
>  function sigint()  { 
>     exit;  
>  }  
>  pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'sigint');  
>  pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'sigint');  
>  ?>
> ```
>
> This way when the process recieves one
>   of those signals, it quits normaly,
>   and the shutdown function gets called. ... (abbreviating to save space, read the full text)

If that is too much hassle, I would consider doing the timing out from within PHP by setting a time limit instead. Reaching the limit will throw a fatal error, and the shutdown function should get called normally.

Comment: That's cool, but I don't think I'll be able to recompile php on a production machine.

Comment: @Wei Why not rely on PHP's time limit instead? (Provided it works on CLI - I have never tried, and some comments [here](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) suggest it is hard coded to 0 - you'd have to try out)

Comment: @Wei also, `pcntl` may already be enabled in your PHP version, check it

Comment: The time limit would only work on one of the kill parameters. I have other parameters in place as well including memory usage and cpu usage.

Comment: @Wei well, you explicitly mentioned the time limit only... No idea whether there is another way, at least not using `kill`

Comment: note that as of PHP 4.3 (which everyone should be at least using), you need to start this answer example code with `declare(ticks = 1);` for  `pcntl_signal` to work. docs: http://php.net/pcntl_signal

Comment: @georgiecasey: I suspect in your above comment, you meant 5.3!