# PHP: what is pcntl_signal used for?

Tags: php

I found a chunk of code that I haven't seen before:

```
declare(ticks = 1);
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, array($this, "catchSignal"));
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, array($this, "catchSignal"));
```

I looked up the function in the PHP documentation, but I still don't understand what this is used for. Please help me understand what this is used for and some examples of where this should be implemented.

Comment: Related recent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909798/register-php-shutdown-function-to-fire-when-a-script-is-killed-from-the-command-l/3909860#3909860

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declare statement states to check for events every "tick". A "tick" being roughly equal to a line of code. This is used in command line PHP scripts so you can catch interrupts and shutdown the script gracefully instead of just killing it.

The `array($this, "catchSignal")` in the `pcntl_signal` function is an odd work around (in my opinion) to support "objects" as parameters. Normally you would just do `$this->catchSignal()`, but PHP doesn't accept class objects as parameters in this case. Thus the "array" syntax.

Basically, if the script is issued an Interrupt or Termination signal, call the `$this->catchSignal()` function before shutting down.

Comment: What would classify as an "interrupt" or "termination" signal?

Comment: In this case, these are Unix terms. SIGINT is an interrupt. Your program can "catch" it and do something. For example, "Are you sure you want to stop?". SIGTERM is a terminate command. Basically, quit now. You can "catch" it and do cleanup before quitting. SIGKILL just kills a program. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)

Answer (score 3):

It's used to install [signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29) handlers. Anything else I could say would just be repeating the article.

Answer (score 3):

The main thing to understand about signal handling is that it's a trap into the operating system. Thus, it can happen outside the normal execution path of your code, interrupting it when it might be doing something else. For instance, if you control-C in *nix, it generally kills whatever program is running. But if that program is doing something sensitive, it might be a bad idea to stop immediately. Thus, a durable program will handle a kill signal in a different manner; gracefully stopping what it's doing before terminating it's execution.

pcntl_signal is the way to do this in PHP.