# how to simulate on_script_close on php(ubuntu), like the .net on_form_close behaviour?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

i have a simple php worker script which is running in the background.

i use a monitor script to make sure that this worker script is indeed running.

the monitor script is running on crontab.

i would like restart the worker process every now and then, using linux kill.

however this create a problem, which is that the worker script might lose the data which is currently handling, if stopped abruptly.

in .net for example, with winforms, u can simply implement on_form_close, how do i accomplish the same with php (linux,ubuntu)?

thanks

Comment: `php worker script which is running in the background.` What are using  cron  , pcntl_fork , popen  or Stackable Workers ?

Comment: `register_shutdown_function` is what you need ....

Comment: thanks! i missed that func somehow.

Comment: It happens once in a while .... Try and also develop your worker in such a way you can resume state

Comment: hi again, im not sure it will be called, when kill is called, mainly due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909798/register-php-shutdown-function-to-fire-when-a-script-is-killed-from-the-command

Comment: now im pretty sure it does not work, as i tested it...

Comment: `pcntl_signal` does not work too ?

Comment: pcntl_signal does work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function) allows you to register functions to run just before the script terminates:

```
register_shutdown_function(function () {
   // ...
});
```

Since you are using signals to kill the process, you should instead install a signal handler:

```
pcntl_signal(SIGQUIT, function () {
    // ...
});
```

See [pcntl_signal](http://php.net/pcntl_signal)

Comment: ahh, great , just to make sure (i will test it later) will register_shutdown_function , will be called on kill?

Comment: mmm, yeah, register shutdown, does not work, when kill is issued.

Comment: hence the second part of the answer :)

Comment: si senior! indeed its a valid solution, however i read about pcntl that it inefficiant, espically the tick part. i ended up implementing a msg system between the procs via php inner queing system. thanks fo r your help!